# Getting last value printed twice when reading file in c++

Tags: c++, io, stream

I'm new to c++. Currently I'm learning how to read and write to a file. I've created a file "nb.txt" with content like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
2 3 4 5 6 7 9
```

I'm using a simple program to read this file, looping until reached EOF.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream in("nb.txt");
    while (in) {
        int current;
        in >> current;
        cout << current << " ";
    }
}
```

What I'm expecting is the program will output all of the values.
But what I'm really getting is this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 9
```

There's a multiple "9" in the output. I don't understand what's happening! Is it because of the while loop?

Can anyone help me to figure out why there is another "9"? Thanks!

Comment: Related: [Why is `iostream::eof()` inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **problem** is that after you read the last value(which is `9` in this case) `in` is not yet set to *end of file*. So the program enters the `while` loop one more time, then reads `in`(which now sets it to *end of file*) and no changes are made to the variable `current` and it is printed with its current value(which is `9`).

To **solve** this problem, you can do the following:

```
int main() {
    ifstream in("nb.txt");
    int current=0;
    while (in >> current) {  //note the in >> curent
       cout << current << " ";
    }
}
```

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/bP2F5vSyX):

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 2 3 4 5 6 7 9
```