# Confused by how stringstream seems to work

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stringstream, stdstring

using stringstream to read individual words from a sentence vs using it to parse comma separated integers behaves differently than how I expected it to.

```
string ok = "hello how is it going";
stringstream ss(ok);
string tmp;
while(ss)
{
    ss >> tmp;
    cout << tmp << endl;
}
```

i'd expect the output to be-

```
hello
how
is
it
going
```

but the output is-

```
hello
how
is
it
going
going
```

what confuses me is if I use it differently-

```
string ok = "10,11,12";
stringstream ss(ok);
int n;
char ch;
while(ss)
{
   ss >> n >> ch;
   cout << n << endl;
}
```

i get the desired output which is-

```
10
11
12
```

and not 12 being repeated as in the case with strings

Comment: Use `while(ss>>tmp)` instead of just `while(ss)` as explained in the [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71182070/getting-last-value-printed-twice-when-reading-file-in-c)

Comment: And the difference in you second example is, that the ss will already be in fail state one iteration earlier, because of you try to read a trailing comma.

Comment: the trailing comma sets it to fail state that was the distinction i didnt get from the dupe